# pass thymeleaf variable as parameter in method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I concatenate the state and my stateCounter to one String. This is my value for my HashMap which stores all the States but I don't get it to to put this variable in my method.

```
<span th:with="stateName=${item.state} + ${item.stateCounter}"></span>
<td th:text="${{order.getStateRepository().get(${stateName})}}"></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

(1) Using a `<td>` tag suggests you are also using a `<table>`. Having a `<span>` tag next to a `<td>` tag inside a table is not valid HTML (assuming this is what it looks like in your template - maybe this is just a copy/paste thing).

(2) If your `order` object has a `stateRepository` field, then you don't need to use a getter `order.getStateRepository()`. You can just use the field name `order.stateRepository`. You are already doing this with `item.state`, for example. Thymeleaf will figure out from the field name how to use the related getter - e.g. `item.getState()`.

(3) The *scope* (availability/visibility) of a local variable, such as `stateName` in `th:with="stateName=${item.state}` is limited to the tag in which it is declared, and also to any sub-tags. You do not have any sub-tags in your `<span>` - therefore the variable is not visible anywhere outside of your span. So, it is not available inside the `<td>` tag.

(4) Do you *need* to use a local variable in your example?

Instead of using `get(stateName)`, you can use the expression referred to by `stateName` directly:

```
get(item.state + item.stateCounter)
```

So overall, this should work (based on the assumptions above):

```html
<td th:text="${order.stateRepository.get(item.state + item.stateCounter)}"></td>
```

Maybe you do need the local variable, of course. It may depend on the wider context of the Thymeleaf template.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [local variable](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables). It will work if you try as follows:

```html
<div th:with="stateName=${item.state} + ${item.stateCounter}">
    <td th:text="${order.getStateRepository().get(stateName)}"></td>
</div>
```